# Distance between any two points after DBSCAN

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, outlier, dbscan

DBSCAN is a clustering model which is robust to detect the outliers also. A parameter $\epsilon$ i.e. radius is an input of the algorithm, a point is said to be outlier if it's circle with radius $\epsilon$ has no point except that point of center. I have detected the outliers for a dataset, but then I observed that all pair distances is less than $\epsilon$. I'm just confused now, Is my understanding of DBSCAN wrong or there should be some mistake in my code?

```
import numpy as np


import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('HomeC.csv')
time_index = pd.date_range('2016-01-01 00:00', periods=503911, freq='min')
#time_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(time_index)

L = []

for i in range(len(time_index)):
    L.append("")
    


    
    
for i in range(len(time_index)):
    if int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) <4 and int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) >= 0: 
        
        L[i] = 'Night'
    if int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) <9 and int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) >= 4: 
        
        L[i] = 'Morning'
    if int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) <12 and int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) >= 9: 
       
        L[i] = 'Late Morning'
    if int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) <15 and int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) >= 12: 
        
        L[i] = 'afternoon'
    if int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) <18 and int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) >= 15:
        
        L[i] = 'late afternoon'
    if int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) <21 and int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) >= 18:
        
        L[i] = 'Evening'
    if int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) <24 and int(str(time_index[i])[10:13]) >= 21:        
        L[i] = 'Late evening'





df = df.iloc[:,:].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder #sklearn is inside numpy module
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
df[:,0] = L
df[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(df[:, 0]) # Converting Categorical feature to numerrical feature

df[:,20] = df[:,20].astype('str') 
df[:,23] = df[:,23].astype('str')
labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
df[:, 20] = labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(df[:, 20])
labelencoder_Z = LabelEncoder()
df[:, 23] = labelencoder_Z.fit_transform(df[:, 23])
df = df[58:,:]

df = df.astype('float')



df = df[:len(df)-1]
df = np.log(df+10)
house1 = []
house2 = []
house3 = []
house4 = []

for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if i % 4 == 0:
        house1.append(df[i])
    elif i % 4 == 1:    
        house2.append(df[i])
    elif i % 4 == 2:    
        house3.append(df[i])
    else:   
        house4.append(df[i])
X_house1 = house1[:5000]
y2 = dbscan(X_house1)
mins = []   
count = 0     
for i in range(5000):
    print(i)
    temp = []
    count = 0
    for j in range(5000):
        if i != j:
            temp.append(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(X[i]-X[j]))))
    if min(set(temp)) > eps:
        count += 1
    mins.append(min(set(temp)))    

    
        
        
        
    house1 = np.array(house1)
    house2 = np.array(house2)
    house3 = np.array(house3)
    house4 = np.array(house4)        
    
    from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
    
    
    
 def dbscan(X):
     clustering = DBSCAN(eps=0.6  , min_samples=200).fit(X)
     y = clustering.labels_
     y_2 = []
     for i in range(len(y)):
         if y[i] != -1:                  
            y_2.append(0)
         else:                   
            y_2.append(1)
     return np.array(y_2)
X = X_house1

eps = 0.6
mins = []   
count = 0     
for i in range(5000):  #Calculating the distance of each pair of points
    print(i)
    temp = []
    count = 0
    for j in range(5000):
        if i != j:
            temp.append(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(X[i]-X[j]))))
    if min(set(temp)) > eps:
        count += 1
    mins.append(min(set(temp)))  
    
print(count,sum(y2)) #count is 0, but should be equal to sum(y2), sum(y2) is total number of the outliers
```

link of the dataset *https://www.kaggle.com/taranvee/smart-home-dataset-with-weather-information*

Comment: I don't know if it's related but maybe the algorithm considers Outlier when only a certain number of points are in the radius. Imagine 2 outliers being really close from each-other, not being labeled as outliers because they have a neighbour, even though they're extremely far from the majority of the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you miss the second parameter: `min_samples=200`

DBSCAN not only detects the outliers, but it mainly detects so-called noise. When we do clustering via DBSCAN, we do not look only at distance `eps=0.6`, but we check if the cluster-candidate is populated with over than `min_samples=200` objects.

You don't see "outliers", but you see all the objects that do not perform the cluster. That is why object can have a neighbor in a ball with radius 0.6, but it can be considered as -1 "noise" cluster.

Comment: Whatever I know is that a point is called core point if it's circle contains at least min_samples points. but non core point is not always outlier.

Comment: Sorry, I have gone through the algorithm again and you are right,